# Komma oder kein Komma in „Du weißt was das bedeutet?“

Tags: punctuation, comma, subordinate-clause

> Du weißt was das bedeutet?

Ich habe das Gefühl, dass ich diesen Satz so ohne Komma schreiben kann, aber sobald vor dem *was* etwas mehr steht, würde ich ein Komma setzen. Nun bin ich Muttersprachler (und -schreiber), und kann meinem Gefühl im Allgemeinen vertrauen, da sich meine langjährige Leseerfahrung darin manifestiert.

Ich habe die Phrase gegoogelt – kein Glück. Den Schreibregeln im Duden zu folgen, fällt mir sehr schwer, weil ja gerade der Weg vom Phänomen zum Namen des Musters so schwer ist.

Liege ich mit *meinem Gefühl* überhaupt richtig? Was ist der grammatikalische Hintergrund?

Comment: Es gibt diese Faustregel, dass zwischen zwei finite Verben ein Komma kommen muss. Du hast zwei finite Verben. Auch wenn diese Regel nicht 100% stimmt — man denke zum Beispiel an zwei nebengeordnete Hauptsätze — ist dies hier ein Indikator für das Komma.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kurz und schmerzfrei, die [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> § 74: Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Der Satz »was das bedeutet« ist ein Nebensatz; erkennbar daran, dass sowohl das Subjekt (*das*) als auch das Objekt (*was*) vor dem konjugierten Verb stehen. Nebensätze sind mit Komma abzugrenzen, demnach ist *ausschließlich* richtig:

> Du weißt, was das bedeutet.

(Ob der Satz als Aussage oder als Frage formuliert ist, ist irrelevant.)

Comment: Danke für die Info. Dann muss ich an meinem Gefühl arbeiten. Wäre es dennoch möglich, dass die Schreibung ohne Komma neuerdings erlaubt ist oder bald wird - schlicht, weil Kommas hier häufig vergessen werden?

Comment: @Wolf Ich hielte es für sehr unwahrscheinlich. Vergessen werden diese Kommas eigentlich nur in salopp geschriebenen Texten; in Zeitungen, Büchern und förmlichen Briefen sollte es immer da sein oder sein Fehlen einen schlechten Eindruck hinterlassen.

Comment: Bei formelhaften unvollständigen Nebensätzen (z. B. „wie bereits gesagt“, „wenn nötig“, „falls möglich“, „wo möglich“, „bitte“) kann man gemäß § 76 das Komma weglassen. Dieser Fall liegt allerdings bei „was das bedeutet“ nicht vor.

Comment: @Loong In diesem Fall würde ich sogar sagen »wo kein konjugiertes Verb, da kein vollständiger (Neben-) Satz«, aber schön, dass die Regeln das noch einmal extrig angeben.

Comment: @Jan: Allerdings ist _bitte_ ein konjugiertes Verb, jedenfalls von seinem Ursprung her.

Comment: @chirlu Und *heute* ist vom Ursprung her zur Hälfte ein Substantiv und wird nicht groß geschrieben. (Vielleicht fällt mir noch ein besseres Gegenbeispiel ein ;))

Comment: @Jan: In meiner Sprache ist _bitte_ auch kein Verb mehr, aber noch lebende ältere Leute fassen es teilweise noch so auf (und setzen dann auch Kommata).

Comment: @chirlu Ich bitte dich, *bitten* ist doch ein gängiges Verb, wobei bei dem oben verwiesenen formelhaften Nebensatz es sich eher nicht um das Verb handelt. Aber ein anderes Verb ist doch viel offensichtlicher: wie bereits *gesagt*.

Comment: @Em1: Erinnere dich, bitte, daran, daß das _bitte_ ein verkürztes _ich bitte darum_ (o.ä.) ist. „Wie bereits gesagt“ hat kein konjugiertes Verb (_wie bereits gesagt wurde_).

Comment: @chirlu Mein Punkt war eben, dass es für mich doch keine Kurzform ist, sondern ein Adverb. Das macht's genau genommen sowieso nicht zu einem Nebensatz, sondern bestenfalls zu einem Einschub (den man natürlich mit Komma abgrenzen kann, aber da greift nun eine ganz andere Regel).

Comment: @Em1: Wie bereits gesagt, ist es für mich auch ein Adverb, aber noch lebende ältere Leute fassen es teilweise noch so auf (und setzen dann auch Kommata).

Comment: `Du weißt.` ist also ein Hauptsatz. Klingt richtig und irgendwie doch auch falsch. Bei `Du weißt es.` habe ich dieses schlechte Gefühl nicht. Mal die Regeln beiseite gelassen, könnte ich mir vorstellen, mit diesem schlechten Gefühl nicht allein dazustehen.

Comment: @Wolf Das Objekt von *wissen* ist in diesem Fall der gesamte Nebensatz (Relativsatz). Ein Relativsatz kann Subjekt und Objekt zu seinem Hauptsatz sein.