# Wird eine genauere Spezifizerung von »das« mit Kommas abgetrennt?

Tags: punctuation, comma, subordinate-clause

Werden im folgenden Satz die eingeklammerten Kommas gesetzt?

> Das(,) was man in der Schule lernt(,) ist durchaus sinnvoll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Komma oder kein Komma in „Du weißt was das bedeutet?“](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25953/komma-oder-kein-komma-in-du-wei%c3%9ft-was-das-bedeutet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, da es ein Nebensatz ist.
Der Hauptsatz könnte auch allein stehen und wäre immer noch verständlich.

Comment: Ob man den Hauptsatz ohne Nebensatz versteht, ist für die Kommasetzung irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Kurz und schmerzfrei, die [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln-woerterverzeichnis_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf):

> § 74: Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Der Satz »was man in der Schule lernt« ist ein Nebensatz; erkennbar daran, dass sowohl das Subjekt (*man*) als auch das Objekt (*was*) vor dem konjugierten Verb stehen. Nebensätze sind mit Komma abzugrenzen, demnach ist *ausschließlich* richtig:

> Das, was man in der Schule lernt, ist durchaus sinnvoll.

Diese Antwort ist im Grunde eine 1:1-Kopie meiner [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/25954) aus [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25953), von welcher diese Frage meines Erachtens ein Duplikat ist.